# iOS twitter login when app is not installed

Tags: ios, swift, twitterkit, twitter-login

In my iOS app I'm using TwitterKit

The problem I have faced is that when twitter app is not installed there is no way to log in user

I saw answers that suggesting adding any callback URL but that doesn't work anymore

I have tried 2 things: search in their docs and found nothing. tried this answer [Tweeting using Twitterkit fails when Twitter app is not installed in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187918/tweeting-using-twitterkit-fails-when-twitter-app-is-not-installed-in-ios-11). This solution doesn't work anymore

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show us what you have tried when app is not installed.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni updated my answer

Comment: @Roma I have same problem check my answer and question. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401016/login-with-twitter-always-return-error

Comment: @chiragshah Thank you! +1 for you for this :)

Comment: my app is only opening in safari, how can i open in Twitter app.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add callback URL in this format**

```
twitter-twitterid://
```

*(Replace "twitterid" with "your twitter app id")*

Comment: my app is only opening in safari, how can i open in Twitter app.?

Comment: where can I find twitter app id

Answer (score 2):

After lot of R&D I got the success. Twitter has made call back url compulsory. I found from this link

You need to add [twitterkit-123456478://](http://twitterkit-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx://) (twitterkit-consumerKey) in call back url at twitter dashboard setting.

I used this method for opening safari (make sure you add safari framework)

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(with: self) { (session, error) in
            if (session != nil) {
                print("signed in as \(session?.userName ?? "")");
            } else {
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")");
            }
        }
```

> Appdelegate

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
           if url.scheme?.caseInsensitiveCompare(("twitterkit-" + TwitterKey.consumerKey)) == .orderedSame{
                TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
            }
            return true
        }
```

Comment: Yes that's correct I'll put @Swalih answer as accepted because he was first. Hope you will understand me. I'll plus this question and your answer at another question similar to this. Thank you!